# What if employer says the workplace is one of the top place

Tags: interviewing

I was in the interview and the employer said the company is one of the best. I was too shy but I was wondering is it correct way to ask in this situation some evidence why the company is the best, or at least how do one measures the goodness of a job?

Comment: Why not just ask them why they claim to be one of the best companies?

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I think _that's_ his question — whether or not it's appropriate to follow up with the employer's claim and ask that (which is definitely fine to follow up with)

Comment: @NickZuber - If that were clarified why he thought it might be inappropriate that might help him get a more helpful answer.

Comment: And remember even the best companies are the worst place to work for some people and even companies that would drive many people crazy are good for others.  Best is subjective, you have to decide what best means to you, not what others say is best. What benefits do you want, what organizational culture do you want? What kind of boss do you want? What kind of co-workers do you prefer? Are the work conditions acceptable, are the actual work tasks teh ones you want to do or teh projects ones that align with  your interests.

Answer (score 14):

> is it correct way to ask in this situation some evidence why the
>   company is the best, or at least how do one measures the goodness of a
>   job?

While it's perfectly reasonable to dig into that response a bit, using the terms "evidence" or "how does one measure the goodness" is phrasing that is likely to come across negatively. To my ears it sounds as if you are questioning the conclusion.

Instead, something like "Wow, that sounds great! Tell me more about what makes this company one of the best." might elicit a better conversation.

Comment: +1 I would point to this as an example of how a short and concise answer can also explain why and how.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings It's Joe's QA background. When you write a test script you make it as simple as possible but no simpler. There's an Einstein joke in there somewhere.